# Transparent modal popup in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup, modal-dialog

I was able to create a transparent modal popup in **Xamarin forms(Version 2.2.*)** by setting the background color of a stack layout to *`Color.FromRgba(0,0,0,0.5)`*.

But the same is not working when i updated my Xamarin Forms to **Version 2.4.***. Do we have any alternate solution to achieve this without using any third party plugins?

I'm talking about using `Xamarin.PushModalAsync(View)` so that i could see through the View.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a color transparent by setting its alpha channel to a value between 0 and 1.

Here is one I have in my resource dictionary

```
   <Color x:Key="BlockingColor">
        <x:Arguments>
            <x:Double>0</x:Double>
            <x:Double>0</x:Double>
            <x:Double>0</x:Double>
            <x:Double>0.75</x:Double>
        </x:Arguments>
    </Color>
```

The fourth parameter is the alpha channel. Setting it to 0.75 makes it semi-transparent.

You can then use it in a style

```
    <Style x:Key="BlockingPanel" TargetType="StackLayout">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource BlockingColor}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
    </Style>
```

And then use it in XAML

```
<StackLayout Style={StaticResource BlockingPanel}>
</Stacklayout>
```

Comment: Setting alpha will not work in the latest Xamarin.Forms(2.4) version.

Comment: Just tested this on Android and iOS and it works on both. Running version 2.4.0.280

Comment: ok. how did you push this view using modal popup? Have you used Navigation.PushModal(view)?

Comment: I had a hidden stack layout that I made visible

Comment: Are you saying you have a page, push a model view and by making the background transparent you can see the first page through it?

Comment: **Exactly**. My requirement is have a transparent popup like this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/alertcontroller/Images/okaycancel.png but its not happening with new Xamarin Forms version. I tried Navigation.PushModal(View) with the View with the settings you mentioned. But it didnt work.